# Можно ли в инпуте вывести текст разного цвета?

Tags: css

Есть

```
<input value="Введите E-mail: *" />
```

Можно ли звёздочку окрасить в красный цвет?
Или как-то по-другому можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раскрасить часть значения `placeholder`'а (если вы именно его используете) нельзя. Можно сделать так:

```js
$('#inputLbl, #input').click(function() {
  $('#inputLbl').removeClass('top');
});

$('#input').focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
    $('#inputLbl').addClass('top');
  }
});
```

```css
#input {
  width: 200px;
}

label {
  color: #aaa;
}

label sup {
  color: red;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.top {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" />
<label for="input" class="top" id="inputLbl">E-mail<sup>*</sup></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для выражения "обязательности" поля для заполнения можно использовать: звёздочку в элементе label рядом с input ( например,

```
 <label for="myInput">Введите e-mail <sup>*</sup></label><input type="text" name="" id="myInput">
```

и для sup в css:

```
 label sup { color:red;}
```

) или менять цвет outline с помощью одноимённого css-свойства для input'a ( например, на тот же красный).

Comment: Но суть в том, что текст находится в инпуте. Подругому никак. И убирается при клике на форму.

Answer (score 0):

Именно **текст разного цвета вывести в input нельзя**, но сделать то, что вы хотите, можно.

Вариант со стилями и абсолютным позиционированием другого элемента привели выше.

Вот мой вариант решения этой задачи:
**Суть идеи**: использовать в качестве фона картинку вместо текста.

**p.s.** Ее можно генерировать средствами **php** "на лету".

```js
function removeBackground(x) {
  x.style.background = "white";
}

function addBackground(x) {
  if (x.value === "") {
    x.style.background = "url(http://i.imgur.com/pCbyu2p.png) no-repeat 10px center";
  } else {
    removeBackground(x);
  }
}
```

```css
#mail {
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pCbyu2p.png) no-repeat 10px center;
  height: 25px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<input id="mail" type="text" onfocus="removeBackground(this);" onblur="addBackground(this);" value="" />
```