# Как в placeholder вставить * красного цвета?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, placeholder

```
<input type="text" id="reviews_nm" class="input_field" placeholder="Ваше имя*" name="name">
```

Чтобы знак * был красного цвета?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/WddQ8/1/

```css
.place_holder {
    z-index: 100;    
    left: 10px;
    cursor: text;   
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 100%;    
    display: none;
    color: lightgrey;
}

.placeinput input:invalid + .place_holder {
     display: inline;
}

/*вся проблема в том, если placeholder больше инпута*/
.placeinput {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.place_holder span {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="placeinput">
    <input required="1" type="text" id="text" />
    <div class="place_holder">Some text<span>*</span></div>
</label>

<label class="placeinput">
    <input required="1" type="text" id="text" />
    <div class="place_holder">другой текст text<span>*</span></div>
</label>
```

[вот ещё вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/C33fy/) правда с поддержкой браузеров я не уверен, оно даже через  запятую не стало работать (по факту, только в chrome работает).

[вот вариант про который я говорил в самом начале](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XtLQK/)

Comment: @eicto, мне понравилось ваше решение, из него узнал для себя кое-что новое. Жаль, что оно не поддерживается IE вообще.

Comment: [тут пишут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772367(v=vs.85).aspx) IE>=10

Comment: @eicto, я проверял в IE 10, "плэйсхолдер" не пропадает при наборе текста.  
Пропадает только при повторной установке фокуса в input с текстом...

Comment: забавно, получается у них invalid не меняется при наборе, ну можно с focus совместить.

Answer (score 5):

приблизительно так

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WddQ8/

```js
$('#text').focus(function () {
    $('#hint').hide();
});

$('#text').blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
        $('#hint').show();
    }
});
```

```css
input {
    width: 200px;
}
label {
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    left: -200px;
    cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<label for="text" id="hint">Some text<span style="color: red">*</span>
</label>
```

Посмотрите

[Можно ли в инпуте вывести текст разного цвета?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/238919/css-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: **cursor: text;** для label и вообще замечательно

Comment: только зачем там js ?

Comment: JavaScript-ом заставляем div появляться и исчезать по событиям focus и blur input-а

Comment: @soledar10, решение без скрипта имеется. Ради интереса набросал пример.

Comment: в webkit(blink) оно умеет ::after после placeholder :)

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал.

Answer (score 4):

**[Посмотреть пример:](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/TPBnY/1/)**

**Разметка**

```
<div class="holder">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Some text<span>*</span></label>
</div>
```

**Стили**

```
.holder {
    height: 26px;
    position: relative;
}
.holder input, .holder label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.holder input {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 20px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.holder input:focus {
    background: #ffffff;
}
.holder label {
    height: 26px;
    left: 5px;
    line-height: 26px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.holder label > span {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```