# "Красные звездочки " в плейсхолдере

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все привет!
Кто нибудь знает цивилизованный способ сделать красные звездочки в плейсхолдере в инпуте. Пробовал просто накладывать их поверх, он это оказалось слишком муторно.
Может есть какая нибудь библиотека для это цели?

Comment: дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298676/Как-в-placeholder-вставить-красного-цвета/298683#298683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде ровненько

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px;
  float: left;
}

label span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 12px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: text;
}

input {
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input:invalid + span:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
}

input:invalid + span:after {
  content: '*';
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input required><span placeholder='E-mail (Логин)'></span>
</label>
```