# Разноцветный текст placeholder-a

Tags: html, css, css3, placeholder

Вот пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Внутри плейсхолдера  звездочки бирюзовые,как их втулить?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298676/Как-в-placeholder-вставить-красного-цвета

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  background: #24323b;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 2px solid #7d8b94;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.form-row {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.input-i {
  display: block;
  color: #7d8b94;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .75rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: .5rem; 
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .17s ease-in-out;
}

.input-i i {
  color: #456d6d;
}

.input:focus ~ .input-i {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>  
  <div class="form-row">    
    <input type="text" name="email" class="input" id="email">
    <label for="email" class="input-i">Email Adress <i>*</i></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-row">    
    <input type="text" name="pass" class="input" id="pass">
    <label for="pass" class="input-i">Set a Password<i>*</i></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать `placeholder`, то в нём размещается только текст. И стиль будет общий для:

```
Set A Password *
```

Можно пойти другим путём.

1. Например размещать текст не в `placeholder` а ниже `input` (за ним).

`input{ background: tranparent; }`

Но тогда логику скрытия текста при вводе в `input` нужно реализовать.

2. Вешать `*` извне елемента `input`

   `span{ content: '*'; position:absolute;}`

и так далее
Но прятать если будет клик или ввод по `input`.