# Сложный текст в placeholder

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, placeholder, маска

Можно ли с помощью только css/html сверстать такой `placeholder`:

[image: сложный Placeholder]

Я имею ввиду текст внутри `placeholder`, часть которого в одном начертании, часть в другом и в том числе пунктирное подчеркивание

```css
.search{
  position:relative;
  margin:26px 0 2px;
}
.search-input{
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 57px 12px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
}
.search-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vArC.png") no-repeat center center;
  width:54px;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input class="search-input" type="search" placeholder="Например: Артикул a2343-JFKLFLI3920ee">
  <input class="search-btn" type="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду маску для поля input?

Comment: да, я имею ввиду текст

Comment: Можно попробовать родительскому элементу дать `:before\:after` и туда поместить текст.

Comment: Да, я думала об этом, но на hover, active и focus - ok - этот текст можно убрать, он ведь должен исчезать, если поле заполнено, а если поле не в фокусе, то как убрать befofe/after на заполненное поле при расфокусировке?

Comment: Примерно так: http://codepen.io/alexeyten/pen/ryKzVY

Comment: @alexey-ten именно то что нужно! без js! Можете перевести ваш пример в ответы, и я отмечу ваш ответ как решение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в placeholder вставить \* красного цвета?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298676/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-placeholder-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так:

```css
.input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: text;
}
.input input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 8px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.placeholder::before {
  content: attr(data-before);
}
.placeholder::after {
  content: attr(data-after);
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
input:invalid + .placeholder {
  display: block;
}
input:focus + .placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="input">
  <input required>
  <span class="placeholder"
        data-before="Пример: "
        data-after="BFG-9000"></span>
</label>
```

Это грубый набросок, который надо допиливать до нужного состояния, но общий смысл такой.

Comment: Что-то я перемудрил. Можно же было прямо в span написать и оформить что угодно…

Answer (score 5):

Что если такой вариант, сделать `placeholder` с помощью настоящего элемента (правда понадобится немного кода):

Фишка еще в том, чтобы использовать `<label .. for="search">` чтобы клик по нему передавался в `input`

```js
$('#search').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val().length>0){
       $('.search .placeholder').hide();
   }else{
       $('.search .placeholder').show();
   }

})
```

```css
.placeholder{
   position:absolute;
   top:18px;
   color:#ccc;
   left:22px;
}
.placeholder > span{
   text-decoration:underline;
}

.search{
  position:relative;
  margin:26px 0 2px;
}
.search-input{
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 57px 12px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
}
.search-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vArC.png") no-repeat center center;
  width:54px;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <input class="search-input" type="search" id="search">
  <label class=placeholder for="search">Например: <span>Артикул a2343-JFKLFLI3920ee</span></label>
  <input class="search-btn" type="button">
</div>
```

Comment: Хорошее рабочее решение, но все же хотелось бы обойтись без js

Answer (score 1):

Если без `js`, без `after`\ `before`:

```css
.search{
  position:relative;
  margin:26px 0 2px;
}
.search-input{
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 57px 12px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 52px;
  -moz-border-radius: 52px;
  border-radius: 52px;
}
.search-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vArC.png") no-repeat center center;
  width:54px;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

input+span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 60px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  opacity: 1;
}


input:focus+span{
  display: none;
} 


input[required="required"]:valid +span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <label>
    <input class="search-input" type="search" required="required">
    <span>Например:<i>Артикул a2343-JFKLFLI3920ee</i></span>
  </label>
  <input class="search-btn" type="button">
</div>
```