# Css нужна помощь с placeholder

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в placeholder выделить звездочку что бы задать ей красный цвет?

Comment: код пожалуйста добавьте

Comment: <div class="form_name">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
</div>

Comment: Дубликат: [Как в placeholder вставить \* красного цвета?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298676/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-placeholder-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)