# Помощь с применением focus для input в css

Tags: html, css, css3

Как задать focus так, чтобы при нажатии на поле для ввода Name, Email или Message текст заглушка исчезал. То бишь, чтобы focus сработал на текст заглушку и присвоил ему opacity 0.

```
Вот код в котором нужно это подправить: https://codepen.io/Maref/pen/eYmpLoG
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как в placeholder вставить \* красного цвета?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/298676/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-placeholder-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на CSS.

```css
.o-field {
  position: relative;
}
.o-field__input {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

.o-field__label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.o-field__input:invalid +
.o-field__label {
  opacity: 1;
}

.o-field__input:valid +
.o-field__label,
.o-field__input:focus + 
.o-field__label {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="o-field">
  <input type="text" class="o-field__input" required>
  <label class="o-field__label">Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: А ещё, повесить на `label` свойство `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте атрибут `placeholder` вместо `label`. Это поможет вам в том что бы текст написанным пользователем не залезал на другой.

```
<input class="form_control" id="foo2" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
```

Comment: Но в placeholder, нельзя изменить цвет звёздочки и по этому я сделал по другому. Если как-то можно изменить, то с удовольствием послушаю.

Answer (score 0):

Это решается с помощью свойств active и focus у элемента input. Мы просто узнаем, когда инпут переходит в такие состояния и меняем свойства плейсхолдера.

```css
.form_control:active+.form_text, .form_control:focus+.form_text{
  opacity:0;
}
```

Тут используется смежный селектор +, про его свойства можно подробнее почитать например здесь:http://codeharmony.ru/materials/42

Еще можно добавить немного анимации, например вот так

```css
.form_text{
  transition:opacity 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так.

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}

.test:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test" placeholder="focus me"></input>
```